# How do you automatically scroll a ScrollView as more content is added?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

In my android project I use a scrollview to show a content.  At the end of my content there is a button which is used to add some more trivia. The button works fine and the information is added successfully.

But at the first sight you can't notice the changes.  Adding more content to the scroll view doesn't change the scrollview situation so the user thinks it doesn't add anything.

What I am saying is you need to scroll it yourself to realize there is more content. But as you know famous apps change the situation a little by themselves.   I need to know how can achieve this via Java code .

There is no related code because my code doesn't have any problem, I just want to complete it . I add this line just for escaping from stackoverflow's trap ( as a **Protest**) :

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    >

</ScrollView>
```

How do you automatically scroll a ScrollView as more content is added?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the situation a little" ?

Comment: @Kushtrim it must goes up a little by itself . this helps us to see the new  changes

Comment: You can call scrollTo(int x, int y) method of ScrollView to scroll programatically

Comment: Let me add that as an answer then.

Comment: Vague and wandering description.  This is not phrased as a question which is the conventional form here.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [scrollTo(int x, int y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#scrollTo(int,%20int)) method of ScrollView to scroll programatically.